# How to avoid using singleton in a proper way?

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns

I want to refactor my code to apply clean approach.

I have a class `user`

```
class User { 
    let name: String?
    let id: String
    var isOnline: Bool

    var mesaageHistory = [Message]()

    init(name: String, id: String, isOnlineStatus: Bool) {
        self.name = name
        self.id  = id
        self.isOnline = isOnlineStatus
    }

}
```

Then I'm using fabric pattern to create list of my users.

```
protocol CreateUserProtocol: class {
    func sortArray(inputArr: [User])
}


class CreateUserEntity: CreateUserProtocol {

    static let shared = CreateUserEntity()
    var users = [User]()

    func sortArray(inputArr: [User]){
        var applySortingByDate: Bool = false

        for user in inputArr {
            if !user.mesaageHistory.isEmpty {
                applySortingByDate = true
            }
        }

        if applySortingByDate {
            inputArr.sorted(by: { (first, second) -> Bool in
                (first.mesaageHistory.last?.messageTime)! < (second.mesaageHistory.last?.messageTime)!
            })
        } else {
            inputArr.sorted(by: { (first, second) -> Bool in
                first.name! < second.name!
            })
        }
    }

}
```

One controller is responsible for appending new users, while another is used to retrieve them and bind them to tableView. Everything is working fine, but I think my solution is not good enough for scaling.

Moreover in one of my VC I use to sort my Users to online and offline. I think, that I shouldn't do that in my VC and to put this logic into my `CreateUserEntity`

```
var onlineUsersData = [User]()
var offlineUsersData = [User]()

private func classifyUsers() {
    for user in CreateUserEntity.shared.users {

        print("is user online: \(user.isOnline)")
        print(CreateUserEntity.shared.users.count)

        if user.isOnline == true && !onlineUsersData.contains(user) {
            onlineUsersData.append(user)
        }

        if user.isOnline == false && !offlineUsersData.contains(user) {
            offlineUsersData.append(user)
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to rewrite it in proper way, what can you recommend me?

Answer (score 0):

From my opinion try to use firstly `struct` instead of the `class`.

Example:

```
struct User {
    let name: String
}
```

Then you should figure out where you will be storing these users? Now they are in the memory. So we should define where and how we will be storing them.

So probably for this case we can consider `NSUserDefaults` as core for the class that will store users.After that we should create facade to this class to manage our users.

```
protocol UserStoreFacade {
    func fetch(name withName:String) -> User
    func create(name withName:String) -> User
    func save(user:User)
    func update(name newName:String) -> User
    func delete(name withName:String)
}
```

And `UserStore` that is used to manage user.

```
class UserStore: UserStoreFacade {

    let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "User")

    func fetch(name withName:String) -> User {
         let encodeData = defaults?.dictionary(forKey: withName)
         return User(dictionary: encodeData as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
    }

    func create(name withName: String) -> User {
        return User(name: withName)
    }

    func save(user: User) {
        defaults?.set(user.encode(), forKey: user.name)
    }

    func update(name newName:String) -> User {
        return User(name: newName)
    }

    func delete(name withName:String) {
         defaults?.removeObject(forKey: withName)
    }
}
```

It is quite primitive but still showing case how it is possible to accomplish.

Comment: If you down vote answer try to share you're experience because I am hear also to learn.

Comment: I'm not a profi too, but I think that storing users in UserDefaults doesn't conform the best practice approach.

Comment: @dand1 it is just example in real world you should use more secure ways to store user data. It is just example how it is possible to achieve.

Comment: yes, I got it. 
But should I design a delegate protocol if I want to work with object within my VC?

Comment: You would like to create delegate for the VC to manipulate with user class?